# Postgres Full text search not returning expected results

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm trying to set up a full-text search using Postgres but I've been getting unexpected results.

`SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'ross, john and carrie' ) @@ to_tsquery( 'ross' );` True, what I expect

`SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'ross, john and carrie' ) @@ to_tsquery( 'ross & john' );` Again true and expected.

`SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'ross, john and carrie' ) @@ to_tsquery( 'ross & carrie' );` **False?**

If I look at the result from tsvector, `Carrie` is turned into `Carri`

`'carri':4 'john':2 'ross':1`

I'm assuming that's it's related to the `english` normalization but I don't understand how I can still get the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`to_tsvector()` and `to_tsquery()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html#TEXTSEARCH-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) both support an additional parameter for the [*text search configuration*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/textsearch-intro.html#TEXTSEARCH-INTRO-CONFIGURATIONS). Use the same for both:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'ross, john and carrie')
    @@ to_tsquery ('english', 'ross & carrie' );
```

If you omit the parameter, it defaults to the default setting. I bet your default text search configuration is *not* `'english'`. Check with:

```
SHOW default_text_search_config;
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution was very simple.

Make sure to use the same language in your `ts_query`.

`SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'ross, john and carrie' ) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'ross & carrie' );`